# Description subitem formatting in Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, description, subitem

I'm trying to include a `description` sublist in one of my Beamer frames, using a certain formatting:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{red}$\blacksquare$}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{red}$\blacktriangleright$}
    \setbeamertemplate{description item}{{\color{red}$\blacksquare$}~\textbf{\insertdescriptionitem{}:}}
    \setbeamertemplate{description subitem}{{\color{red}$\blacktriangleright$}~\textbf{\insertdescriptionitem{}:}}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Items, subitems, description}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1.1
            \item Item 1.2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}\vfill%
    \begin{description}
        \item[Description] This is the first description
        \item[Another description] This is the second description
    \end{description}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Subdescription}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Here's some item text
        \item And then this item needs a sublist with descriptions
        \begin{description}
            \item[Subitem] This is the explanation of the first subitem
            \item[Another subitem] And of the second subitem
        \end{description}
        \item Another item
    \end{itemize}\vfill%
    \begin{description}
        \item Second try
        \item Let's see the sublist again
        \begin{description}
            \item[Subitem] This is the explanation of the first subitem
            \item[Another subitem] And of the second subitem
        \end{description}
        \item Final item
    \end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The lists and sublists using `itemize`, as well as lists using `description` (slide 1) all work fine (although the alignment is a little off between the `itemize` and `description` list as well):

[image]

However the subdescriptions (slide 2) are misaligned and use the wrong symbol, regardless of whether I use `description` inside an `itemize` environment or inside another `description` environment:

[image]

The desired output would be something like:

[image]

How do I get Beamer to properly align and format all my `description` and `itemize` lists and sublists?

Comment: (don't use the `utf8x` option with a current latex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use a `description` in your case, an `itemize` environment looks much more appropriate:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{red}$\blacksquare$}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{red}$\blacktriangleright$}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamerfont{structure}{series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Items, subitems, description}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1.1
            \item Item 1.2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}\vfill%
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \structure{Description: } This is the first description
        \item \structure{Another description: } This is the second description
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Subdescription}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Here's some item text
        \item And then this item needs a sublist with descriptions
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \structure{Subitem: } This is the explanation of the first subitem
            \item \structure{Another subitem:} And of the second subitem
        \end{itemize}
        \item Another item
    \end{itemize}\vfill%
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Second try
        \item Let's see the sublist again
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \structure{Subitem: } This is the explanation of the first subitem
            \item \structure{Another subitem: } And of the second subitem
        \end{itemize}
        \item Final item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]